# ¿Cómo logro visualizar una matriz de abajo hacia arriba?

Tags: c, dev-c++

Es decir si mi matriz al llenarla se visualiza:

```
1 2 3 4
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

como puedo lograr que se vea así:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
1 2 3 4
```

mi codigo en c es el siguiente:

```
for(i=0; i<PISO-1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<HAB-1; j++)              
        {
            printf("%d ", reserva[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
```

Comment: En lugar de acceder a `i`, accede a `tamaño - 1 -i`.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso debes acceder a la matriz con un bucle for inverso

```
for (i = tamañoArreglo; i > 0; i--)
{
/* código*/
}
```

Si conoces el tamaño de la matriz, es más sencillo porque colocas el código en hard code, sin necesidad de calcular dinamicamente el tamaño, en ese caso esto te debiera de dar una idea

```
#define DIFFERENCE_ARRAY 1

int main()
{
    size_t i, x;
    int array[5][4] = 
    {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
        { 9, 10, 11, 12 },
        { 13, 14, 15, 16 },
        { 17, 18, 19, 20 }
    };


    for (i = 5; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
            printf("%d ", array[i - DIFFERENCE_ARRAY][x]);      

        printf("\n");
    }

    getchar();
    
}
```

El resultado sería este

```
17 18 19 20
13 14 15 16
9 10 11 12
5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: En el caso de una matriz de 5*4 como defino el tamaño?

Comment: Realice unas adecuaciones a la respuesta, espero te den claridad

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que haz introducido tus digitos

```
int f=3,c=4;
int arr[f][c];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        cin>>arr[i][j];
    }
}

1 2 3 4
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Puedes recorrer de arriba hacia abajo de la siguiente manera:

```
for(int i = f-1; i >= 0; i--){
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Lo que podemos observar es que mi variable i se va a encargar de iterar las filas y estoy empezando desde la ultima fila i=2 hasta la primera i=0;
y como resultado obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
1 2 3 4
```